# elasticsearch, stats aggregation on multiple fields JAVA API

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have the following aggregation query that I tested and run fine. I am wondering how to build the equivalent query using its JAVA API. In fact I have a `List<String>` of each element I'd like to see the stats. How can I do this dynamically?

Thank you in advance.

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "value_stats" :{
      "stats": {
        "field" : "value"
      }
    },
    "qty_stats":{
      "stats": {"field" : "qty"}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to add aggregations using their [`AggregationBuilders`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-aggs.html)

```
// 1. replace this list of fields with yours
List<String> statFields = getFields();

// 2. bootstrap the query
SearchRequestBuilder search = node.client().prepareSearch()
    .setSize(0).setFrom(0)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

// 3. add a stats aggregation for each of your fields
for (String field : statFields) {
    search.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.stats(field+"_stats").field(field));
}

// 4. execute the query
SearchResponse response = search.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: I thought  I can only call search.addAggregation() once. Thanks !